# Can't find the memory leak in this snippet

Tags: php, debugging

using PHP Version 5.3.5
I am going insane. 
This piece of code is giving me hard time. After I refresh the page on Apache a few times, I get weird results. I think I have a memory leak here, but I can't find out why.
Please help !

```
<?php 


function ost($active_sub_time,$arr_subscription_values)
{

    $result=0;

    while($active_sub_time>=12)
    {
        $active_sub_time-=12;
        $result+=($arr_subscription_values['COST_12']);
    }

    while($active_sub_time>=6)
    {
        $active_sub_time-=6;
        $result+=($arr_subscription_values['COST_6']);
    }
    while($active_sub_time>=3)
    {
        $active_sub_time-=3;
        $result+=($arr_subscription_values['COST_3']);
    }

    while($active_sub_time>=1)
    {
        $active_sub_time-=1;
        $result+=($arr_subscription_values['COST_1']);
    }

    if($active_sub_time>0)
        $result+=($active_sub_time)*($arr_subscription_values['COST_1']);

    if (!is_numeric($result))
    {
        echo"<br> Bug occurred";break; // print other values if necessary
    }

    return $result;
}

$datetime1 = date_create('2009-01-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2001-11-09');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
$num_of_months = ($interval->y)*12 + ($interval->m) + ($interval->d)/(cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $datetime2->format("m"), $datetime2->format("Y")));

$v = array('COST_1'=>'3.99','COST_3'=>'9.99','COST_6'=>'15.99','COST_12'=>'24.99');
echo "OPT value for $num_of_months months=".ost($num_of_months,$v);

?>
```

I do get this result at first:

```
OPT value for 86.066666666667 months=183.176
```

But after a few refreshes I get this :

```
OPT value for G.GMMMMMMMMMMMN months=183.176
```

Does anyone know why this is ?
Thanks

Comment: Very strange. Sorry, can't reproduce it.

Comment: $datetime1 and $datetime2 don't change during refreshes?

Comment: no, they don't, this is the exact piece of code I am running. @John Watson, it takes me around 6-10 refreshes to get the error

Comment: Too many parens... not a solution, just a comment....

Comment: Ran it (command line php) 10,000 times, can't reproduce. Try printing out the raw values for $interval->{y,m,d}

Comment: @Mikhail, OPT value for G.GMMMMMMMMMMMN months=183.176
interval->y=7
interval->m=2
interval->d=2

Comment: what php version are you running?

Comment: @Ted, is this your exact code, or is the ost() function located elsewhere? (You should edit your OP to include php version since people keep asking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot reproduce, I used your code exactly, and executed it multiple times. It displays the same result.

There may be an issue with your server, or mashing refresh over and over is causing some kind of problem or memory limit.

Check your php.ini and see if your memory limit is set too low, or max requests?

Comment: My server handles the whole project I am running more or less. memory limit is 128M, is that not enough for this piece of code ?

Comment: 128M is high.  I certainly wouldn't expect increasing it to help.

Comment: What version of php are you running, could be a bug particular to that version (which would explain why some other people can't reproduce it)